# how do you get the first letter of a name from user input and put it into a if loop?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the task of a book for Python where I need the user to input their name. I then have to check the first letter of that name and print it out in uppercase letters IF it starts with a vocal. Else, I have to tell the user that their name does not begin with a vocal. Now my program keeps spitting out that it doesn't start with a vocal even though the input DID start with a vocal. Here's the latest variation:

```
name = input()

if name[0] == 'A''a''E''e''I''i''O''o''U''u':
    print(f"{name.upper}")
else:
    print("Your name doesn't start with a vocal!")
```

I tried my best to change around what could prevent from getting the first letter, etc. But I don't know other methods than to get the letter from a substring, so maybe there is another way? Whatever, I'd like to know what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This is an efficient way to do it

Change the `if`:

```
if name[0] in "AaEeIiOoUu":
        print(f"{name.upper()}")
```

Rest of the code can stay the same.

#### The mistake in your original code was to place the options one-after-another

That is the same as just concatenating them into one huge string. Your original code was, in effect, testing whether the *first* character of `name` was, literally, `AaEeIiOoUu`, which of course it could never be.

#### To prove the source of the error, try this code

```
test = "A" 'b'     'C' 'd'    """E"""
print(test)
```

You will get

```
AbCdE
```

Comment: and then it's gonna print out `<function object>` or sth

Comment: Thanks! @Timm Hagen - you also needed a `()` after the `upper`.

Answer (score 1):

Equal operator checks equality, you probably want to check if the first letter is a vowel, so the in operator is the right thing to use.

```
name = input()
if name[0].lower() in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
    print(f"{name.upper()}")
else:
    print("Your name doesn't start with a vocal!")
```